# Camera view not working on BLENDER 2.8

Tags: camera

I can't seem to position my camera properly so that my scene is in view all of a sudden. When I press Ctrl + Alt + Num0 a box with a blank screen is displayed and any attempt to position the camera moves it to a completely different position. My camera  is positioned as follows:
[image]

[image]

This is the view from the camera:

[image]

Any suggestions? This does not work in RENDERED/SOLID or Look Dev on BLENDER 2.8

Comment: Check the clipping range for the camera, it might be too small for your scene.

Comment: Is that under view when you press "n" or under camera itself?

Comment: https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/render/cameras.html#properties